# call to setter gives unrecognized selector error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, subclass, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to subclass NSString to give it a property that is another NSString. No matter what I try with @synthesize or @dynamic or manually coding my setters and getters, I keep getting this "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error when I compile.

I know this has probably already been answered but after looking through about 15 other "unrecognized selector" questions on this site I am still at a loss. Sorry, I started coding VERY recently so I'm probably just missing something exceedingly simple.

Furigana.h

```
@interface Furigana : NSString

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *forKanji;

-(void)setForKanji:(NSString *)forKanji; //fails the same with or without this line

@end
```

Furigana.m

```
#import "Furigana.h"

@implementation Furigana
@synthesize forKanji = _forKanji;
//@dynamic forKanji; tried this

-(NSString *)forKanji { //also fails when custom setter/getters are left out
    if(!_forKanji) _forKanji = [[NSString alloc] init];
    return _forKanji;
}

-(void)setForKanji:(NSString *)forKanji {
    if(!_forKanji) _forKanji = [[NSString alloc] init];
    _forKanji = forKanji;
}

@end
```

Reibun.m

```
#import "Furigana.h"

-(NSArray *)parseFurigana:(NSArray *)unparsedData {
    NSMutableArray *furigana = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //of Furigana
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < [unparsedData count]; x++){
        NSArray *components = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        components = [[unparsedData objectAtIndex:x] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        Furigana *newFurigana = [[Furigana alloc] init];
        newFurigana = [components objectAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"stored string: %@",newFurigana); //so far so good
        newFurigana.forKanji = [components objectAtIndex:0]; //crash
        //[newFurigana setForKanji:[components objectAtIndex:0]]; //this fails too
        [furigana addObject:newFurigana];
    }
    return furigana;
}
```

Comment: Do not subclass NSString for this. That is a bad design. Create an NSObject subclass with two string properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the line that breaks your code:

```
newFurigana = [components objectAtIndex:1];
```

It *replaces* the object that you have allocated using `[[Furigana alloc] init]` with an `NSString` object, which does not respond to `setForKanji:` selector.

The assignment replaces `newFurigana` object, not the content of it. The content cannot be changed, because you derive from `NSString`, which is *immutable*.

Replace the `init` with `initWithString`, call `[super initWithString:]` from it, and make the initialization inside your loop look like this:

```
Furigana *newFurigana = [[Furigana alloc] initWithString:[components objectAtIndex:1]];
```